# How to assign a name to a cell in relation to calendar date?

Tags: excel, vba

I created a Calendar in Excel using VBA and I wanted to know how to assign specific names to cells in relation to the calendar date. If possible could I substitute the names using a Userform name selection in relation to the calendar date.

[image]

```
    Sub CreateCalendar()
Dim csheet As Worksheet
Set csheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

selDate = [b1]
fMOn = DateSerial(Year(selDate), Month(selDate), 1)
lMon = CDate(Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(fMOn, 0))

stRow = 4

'clear last cal
Range("B4:V4").ClearContents
Range("B10:V10").ClearContents
Range("B16:V16").ClearContents
Range("B22:V22").ClearContents
Range("B28:V28").ClearContents
Range("B34:V34").ClearContents


'determine what weekday 1st is. . .
If Weekday(fMOn) = 1 Then
         stCol = 2
ElseIf Weekday(fMOn) = 2 Then
         stCol = 5
ElseIf Weekday(fMOn) = 3 Then
         stCol = 8
ElseIf Weekday(fMOn) = 4 Then
         stCol = 11
ElseIf Weekday(fMOn) = 5 Then
         stCol = 14
ElseIf Weekday(fMOn) = 6 Then
         stCol = 17
ElseIf Weekday(fMOn) = 7 Then
         stCol = 20
End If

For x = 1 To Day(lMon)
       If FirstT = Empty Then
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the code!

Comment: Are you asking basically how to create a [Named Range](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4D0F13AC-53B7-422E-AFD2-ABD7FF379C64)?

Comment: Please explain the manual process which you want to automate - it's not clear what you want to do here.

Comment: `stCol = 2 + ((Weekday(fMOn) - 1) * 3)`

Comment: To assign names to cells that react to the calendar date. it is used to see who is in office at a specific date. For example,for the second  week  David is in office MON. WED, and  FRI while Mary is in office TUE, THUR, Friday. Also, the ability to swap days if they wanted to change shifts.

Comment: Also, when i say to react to the calendar date I mean numerical date and the month to date in cell B1